# Where are the CommonJS modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, commonjs

From time to time I hear that CommonJS http://www.commonjs.org/ is an effort to create a set of modular javascript components but frankly I have never understood anything of it.

Where are the these modular components I can use? I don't see much on their homepage.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

CommonJS is only a standard that specifies a way to modularize JavaScript, so CommonJS itself does not provide any JavaScript libraries.

CommonJS specifies a `require()` function which lets one import the modules and then use them, the modules have a special global variable named `exports` which is an object which holds the things that will get exported.

```
// foo.js ---------------- Example Foo module
function Foo() {
    this.bla = function() {
        console.log('Hello World');
    }
}

exports.foo = Foo;

// myawesomeprogram.js ----------------------
var foo = require('./foo'); // './' will require the module relative
                            // in this case foo.js is in the same directory as this .js file
var test = new foo.Foo();
test.bla(); // logs 'Hello World'
```

The Node.js standard library and all 3rd party libraries use CommonJS to modularize their code.

One more example:

```
// require the http module from the standard library
var http = require('http'); // no './' will look up the require paths to find the module
var express = require('express'); // require the express.js framework (needs to be installed)
```

Comment: So CommonJS just specifies require()? That's it? It sounds "bigger" than that when you are reading about it :)

Comment: @wend Well it also defines an anonymous wrapper function to encapsulate the modules content, but again how exactly that function looks is left to the implementation, the `require` function and the `exports` object is all what the implementations have to share. So yeah, it sounds pretty big with all the specifications and standards on their site :D

Comment: So commonJS is just a way of doing export that most libraries adopted? it's not from a derived piece of code, but can be used with JS anytime without any installation?

Answer (score 1):

The idea, it seems (I wasn't aware of this), is to provide javascript to more than just web browsers. For example, [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) supports javascript for querying.